# Why is Bitmasking not working for long long integer?

Tags: c++, bitmask

I was trying to understand Bitmasking and came across this problem where i have to store number upto 64
(1<n<64) in O(1) complexity :
Here I'm trying to make a Data Structure to store values as a set but in O(1) as I have constraints of 64

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
typedef vector<int> vi;


class BitMask
{

public:
    ll n;
    BitMask()
    {
        //call the class as Bitmask varname;
        n = 0;
    }
    void insert(long long x) {
        n |= (1 << x);
    }
    void deleteItem(long long x) {
        if (n & (1 << x)) {
            n &= ~(1 << x);
        }
    }
    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            if (n & (1 << i)) {
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }

};

//implementation
int main() {
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif
    BitMask obj1;
    //insertion

    obj1.insert(1);
    obj1.insert(5);
    obj1.insert(3);
    obj1.insert(60);


    //print
    obj1.print();
    cout << endl;
    //deletion
    obj1.deleteItem(5);

    obj1.print();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here The output was supposed to give

> 1, 3, 5, 60

> 1,3,60

But instead this is giving

> 1
> 3
> 5
> 28
> 33
> 35
> 37
> 60

> 1
> 3
> 28
> 33
> 35
> 60

Can some tell why these extra bits are called out?

Comment: You're iterating through the bits one-by-one. If you want to set individual bits, you'll have to set those bits, and nothing else.
Setting individual bits goes like this: `n |= 0x01; n |= 0x02; n |= 0x04; n |= 0x08; n |= 0x10; n |= 0x20;` etc

Comment: To set each bit, double the last value. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, etc

Comment: @SimonC Thank you for your insightful comment . But here the issue I'm facing is how is 28th 33rd and 35th bits are set?

Comment: You need `1LL << x` and `1LL << i`, otherwise your bitshifting an int beyond its range and it won't have the expected result.

Comment: `typedef long long ll; typedef vector<int> vi;` -- Obvious signs of using "competitive coding" websites to learn C++.  There is no need to obfuscate the code here -- spell out these types instead of hiding them behind macros/typedefs.  You could have easily used something that conveyed the type, `int64_t` -- that is a mere 5 more keystrokes than `ll`, which looks like the number `11` when viewing your code.

Comment: @Artyer Thank you very much for the insightful comment . This is correct .Thank you

Comment: Note that (1 << 62LL) is typically 0 with compiler warning while (1LL << 62) is 4611686018427387904 without compiler warning.

Comment: The duplicate question is for C, not C++.  You can't expect the people with C++ questions to look for answers in C, unless we are all willing to admit that they are related.  This implies posting questions tagged [c] AND [c++] is sometimes ACCEPTABLE or even RECOMMENDED (like the duplicate question designated for this question).